# In Jython, how can I create unicode string from UTF-8 byte sequence?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, jython, decoding

A Japanese Unicode character 'あ's UTF-8 representation is a three bytes sequence, E38182. And I have it in a Jython's list like this;

```
>>> [0xE3, 0x81, 0x82]
[227, 129, 130]
```

Can I convert this UTF-8 byte sequcne list to a Jython's unicode string? I want to output 'あ' by printing the unicode string like the following;

```
str = convert_utf8_list_to_unicode([0xE3, 0x81, 0x82])
print str # => あ
```

## Environment

- OS: Mac OS X 10.9.3 Mavericks
- Jython: 2.5.3
- Java: 1.6.0_65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [0xE3, 0x81, 0x82]
print "".join([chr(c) for c in a]).decode('UTF-8')
```

This works in regular Python for me. I don't know if it is different in Jython.